# Scroll follow div stop follow at a position and start other div follow

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, position

I would like to do a jQuery scroll follow like this:

http://www.girlfriendnyc.com/portfolio

I want that the right sidebar stops at the specific position and then, other sidebar starts.

I don't have any idea how to do.

I hope your help. Sorry for my english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem.

Here is a little example, if it helps someone:

http://jsfiddle.net/e4VzT/2/

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer to help you get started:

During scroll event, use javascript to detect the position of main content vs window scrollTop and then adjusting the right sidebar's css to position:fixed or absolute accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I've been doing some tests, and this is the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/e4VzT/

My problem now is how can I do for to have different items? 

Like my previous example: http://www.girlfriendnyc.com/portfolio

Thanks